# Set in the Complex Plane

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I describe the set:

$$ \left\vert z - {\rm i}\,\right\vert = 3\left\vert z\right\vert $$

It does appear quite unfamiliar.

Attempt: $$ \left\vert\frac{z-i}{z}\right\vert = 3  $$ so,
$$ \left\vert 1 - {\rm i}\,\frac{1}{z}\right\vert = 3 $$

But this seems to be even more difficult to visualize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Square both sides, and write $z = x + iy$:

$$9(x^2 + y^2) = |x + i (y - 1)|^2 = x^2 + (y - 1)^2$$

Rearranging,

$$8x^2 + 8y^2 + 2y - 1 = 0$$

Divide through by $8$ and find

$$x^2 + y^2 + \frac{1}{4} y = \frac{1}{8}$$

or even better,

$$x^2 + y^2 + \frac{1}{4} y + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Try rewriting the left side as the equation of a circle.

Comment: Here's a hint on what "rewriting as a circle" means: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/completing-square.html

Answer (score 2):

Observe the notion of distance when you write $|z-i|=a$ or $3|z|=b$.

The first equation describes a circle with radius $a$ and center on the point $(0,1)$. The second one describes a circle with radius $b/3$ and center at the origin.

$|z-i|=3|z|$ should describe a curve such that each point has it's distance to $(0,1)$ tree times the distance to the origin.

It will be a circle. More about this subject:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius